# Fluent NHibernate Test VerifyTheMappings

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Given the following

```
    [Test]
    public void VerifyMappings()
    {
        new PersistenceSpecification<Address>(Session)
            .CheckProperty(x => x.AddressLine1, "190 House 12")
            .VerifyTheMappings();
    }
```

The following will attempt to do a read and write to the datbase, however it leaves the record. Is it possible to delete this record using the fluent framework?

Answer (score 3):

Just use something like this in your `[TearDown]`:

```
var currentSession = NHibernateSession.Current;
if (currentSession.Transaction.IsActive) {
    currentSession.Flush();
    currentSession.Transaction.Rollback();
}
```

That will rollback the current transaction.